# Radio transmission on my whatsapp voice note

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp

I was sending a voice note to a friend and when I listened to it, the first ~6 seconds were completely normal and then something weird happened. [A radio transmission from some radio station](https://vimeo.com/514693345) (I don't know which one) cut in after a weird sound.

Does anyone know what could have happened? Is it possible some radio transmission could have mixed up with my voice note? Do I need to be worried about my privacy?

Ps: no, it wasn't some radio app on my phone, I checked that. I wasn't listening to anything either, the room was silent.

I've tried saying the same thing in a voice note and nothing happened. Also, the phone is an iPhone 12 pro max without a built-in radio.

Comment: Privacy issues would be an issue if your data was going out. This is a problem of a signal coming in.

Answer (score -1):

Injected parasitic frequencies used to be quite common in the days of AM radio. Close or particularly powerful AM radio station signals showed up everywhere, I've even gotten radio stations on vinyl record players and audio amplifiers.

AM radio is still around today but much less common, but that's what I think is most likely.

Other non-AM transmitters that are really close can occasionally induce audio signals but that's much less common.

In any case, this is essentially outside interference. It may degrade you recordings but it's not a privacy issue.